# Trait 'Exportable' not found in Laravel Excel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I have imports:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
```

**And class:**

```
class ArchivingController extends Controller implements WithMultipleSheets
{

    use Exportable;

}
```

Why I get message:

> Trait 'Exportable' not found

Comment: Is your Trait in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `use Exportable;` to

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
```

you need it to have an alias loaded in `app.php` in the aliases to use it as

```
use Exportable;
```

Comment: Thank you, now I get this message after your advice: `Class App\Http\Controllers\ArchivingController contains 1 abstract method and must `

Comment: Seems one method from WithMultipleSheets is necessery

Comment: @OPV yes, one (or more) of the concern need a function declaration for it to not generate the error